# How to prevent Mac OSX Preview from modifying original image?

Tags: macos, mac, images, preview

I like to use Preview from Mac OSX to view photo because it is preinstalled and fast. But the annoyance is that whenever I edit photo, like resizing, the original got modified immediately. This is very annoying for situation like resizing an image for e-mail only find out later that the image is permanently resized to a lower resolution. How can I prevent Preview from making changes to original unless I save it explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

In my version of Preview (El Capitan), changes are not saved immediately--after making a change, if I close the window, Preview asks if I want to "Revert changes" (which leaves the file unchanged). If your version is working differently, a workaround might be File ---> Revert To, which should let you recover previous versions (if you are using Time Machine).

Comment: In my case (also El Capitan), when I make an accidental change to a PDF file, immediately the PDF file on disk was changed (and no question asked when closing the document). But we can use "Revert to" as Dopey said. To enable the prompt "Do you want to save changes...", go to System Preferences >> General >> Ask to keep changes when closing documents. See: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7356773 .

Answer (score 1):

That's just the way Preview works.

When I want to make changes, but save the original, I usually use "Export..." or Duplicate, both of which can be found under the File menu of Preview.